# Can i use the google play store to retrieve some news data for my app?

Tags: android, google-play, feed

You may have seen this in games/apps that on the first screen you get some "news" like "expansion now available" or "check out the other new game". The way i would implement it is by using a server/website with a php script that the app queries and it then gets a JSON with the news. However i am not a "php guy" and i understand that with a big app and lots of news this could create quite the traffic and thus cost (in a very extreme scenario).

So i wondered if i could use (or abuse) some feature of the store itself.

Another scenario would be that (worst case) after patching a new bug is introduced and i want users to know that a fix will be available shortly. Most users these days won't go to a website etc to find out if someone is working on this, they close the app or even deinstall and give it a bad rating. If they could read about a fix on the very first screen it might mitigate this.

I am aware that all this is not exactly best practice but i still want to know about it.

Comment: Is that news a part of your app or ads? In any case you can create an option "Show news" with sum. "need same traffic" etc. (default is off)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that in an answer please ? And i would use it for the app and not third party ads but it would be more the usual newsletter type information and not vital app info.

Comment: User must have option set newsletter to off to save traffic